# What does the 'public' filter in the SoundCloiud API mean, and does it imply 'streamable'?

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am fetching a list of tracks using the SoundCloud API, but I only want tracks that the user has set as public and also allowed to be embedded outside SoundCloud.

What would be an appropriate value for the `filter` parameter?

Although not documented, it seems like I can combine values in the `filter` parameter, for example `filter=public,streamable`. Does `public` actually imply streamable, or do I have to filter by both to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Unless that user has authenticated with the API via your app, then you'll only get the public tracks anyway. `streamable` should be fine. Alternatively, just fetch them all and you could filter by yourself by removing items which don't have a `stream_url` property.

Comment: But what if the track is public, but widget functionality (i.e. embedding) is turned off? There are "Widget enabled" and "Apps enabled" track properties when editing the track on SoundCloud, how do these settings affect what shows up in the API call for either "public" and/or "streamable" as filter?